# Relation is DS.PromiseMany instead model and data

Tags: ajax, ember.js, ember-data, relation

What I need is:
1) Represent list of partners

```
App.Partner= DS.Model.extend(
    {
        name: attr(),
        site: attr(),
        contacts: DS.hasMany('partner-contact', { async: true, polymorphic: true })
    }
);
```

2) and names of partners contacts

```
App.PartnerContact = DS.Model.extend(
    {
        name: attr(),
        phone: attr(),
        post: attr(),
        email: attr(),
        partnerId: attr(),
        partner: DS.belongsTo('partner')
    }
);
```

So I have route:

```
App.CallsMyContactsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    //needs: "partner-contacts",
    model: function () {
        return this.store.find('partner');  
    }
});
```

And template:

```
{{#each partner in model}}
        <tr class="gradeA even" role="row">
            <td class="sorting_1">{{partner.name}}</td>
            <td>{{partner.name}}</td>
            <td>{{partner.phone}}</td>
            <td class="center">

                {{partner.contacts}}
            {{#each contact in partner.contacts}}
                {{contact.name}}
            {{/each}}
            </td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
    {{/each}}
```

But {{partner.contacts}} is DS.PromiseManyArray
And it ever doesn't make a query to server.

Answer from server (Partners)

```
{  
   "Partner":[  
      {  
         "id":4,
         "name":"CompanyNamej",
         "site":"www.no-site.ru"
      },
      {  
         "id":13,
         "name":"test",
         "site":"sdasdasd"
      },
      {  
         "id":14,
         "name":"",
         "site":""
      }
   ]
}
```

What is the problem?

```
DEBUG: Ember      : 1.10.0
vendor.js:16928DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.15
vendor.js:16928DEBUG: jQuery     : 2.1.3
```

Comment: What does your response from server look like when getting the partners?

Comment: This
{"Partner":[{"id":4,"name":"CompanyNamej","site":"www.no-site.ru"},{"id":13,"name":"test","site":"sdasdasd"},{"id":14,"name":"","site":""}]}
I have updated answer.

Comment: that's why, you don't have the contacts defined on the partners.  You should have a property contacts : [1,2,3] where [1,2,3] are the ids of the contacts

Comment: Wow! Ive spent about 5 hours, I'm so thankful to u!