# Couldn't access related models in ember.js 2.0 using ember-data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I'm trying to display a simple dynamic form using ember.js, im pretty new to ember and front-end frameworks in general.

I am using

- Ember      : 2.0.0
- Ember Data : 2.0.0-beta.1
- jQuery     : 1.11.3
- ember-cli  : 1.13.6

The JSON payload is the following: some fields are to be generated and some elements have to be enabled.

JSON:

```
{
    "create-fields": [{
        "id": 1,
        "field": "widgetName",
        "label": "Widget Name",
        "tooltip": "Widget Name",
        "category": "textfield",
        "url": "",
        "required": true,
        "widgetform_id": 1
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "field": "APIKey",
        "label": "API Key",
        "tooltip": "API Key",
        "category": "textfield",
        "url": "",
        "required": true,
        "widgetform_id": 1
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "field": "Campaign",
        "label": "Select Campaign",
        "tooltip": "Select Campaign",
        "category": "select",
        "url": "campaigns/",
        "required": false,
        "widgetform_id": 1
    }, {
        "id": 4,
        "field": "checkbox",
        "label": "Sample Checkbox",
        "tooltip": "Sample Checkbox",
        "category": "checkbox",
        "url": "",
        "required": false,
        "widgetform_id": 1
    }],
    "enable-fields": [{
        "id": 1,
        "field": "showAdvanced",
        "required": false,
        "widgetform_id": 1
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "field": "notification",
        "required": false,
        "widgetform_id": 1
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "field": "enableNotif",
        "required": false,
        "widgetform_id": 1
    }, {
        "id": 4,
        "field": "email",
        "required": false,
        "widgetform_id": 1
    }, {
        "id": 5,
        "field": "phone",
        "required": false,
        "widgetform_id": 1
    }, {
        "id": 6,
        "field": "reqType",
        "required": false,
        "widgetform_id": 1
    }, {
        "id": 7,
        "field": "dataFormat",
        "required": false,
        "widgetform_id": 1
    }, {
        "id": 8,
        "field": "appendUrlParams",
        "required": false,
        "widgetform_id": 1
    }],
    "widgetforms": [{
        "id": 1,
        "formname": "Edit Widget",
        "enable-field_ids": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
        "create-field_ids": [1, 2, 3, 4]
    }]
}
```

//models

widgetform.js:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    formname: DS.attr(),
    createFields: DS.hasMany('createFields'),
    enableFields: DS.hasMany('enableFields')
});
```

create-field.js:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    field: DS.attr(),
    label: DS.attr(),
    tooltip: DS.attr(),
    category: DS.attr(),
    url: DS.attr('string', {defaultValue: ""}),
    required: DS.attr('boolean'),
    widgetform: DS.belongsTo('widgetform')
});
```

enable-field.js:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    field: DS.attr(),
    required: DS.attr('boolean'),
    widgetform: DS.belongsTo('widgetform')
});
```

template

widgetform.hbs: The hbs doesn't have all the fields it is just a mockup.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
{{#each model as |form|}}
<form class="form-horizontal">
<fieldset>
<header id="header">
  <h1>{{form.formname}}</h1>
</header>
<section id="main">
    <ul id="field-list">
        {{form.createFields}}
        {{#each form.createFields as |element|}}
            <li>test1  {{element.field}}</li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</section>
</fieldset>
</form>
{{/each}}
</div>
```

So far I've been able to see the data in the respective models using ember-inspector in chrome.

However, in the template when using the `{{form.createFields}}` I get a `<DS.PromiseManyArray>`, and the `{{form.createFields.content}}` is a `<DS.ManyArray>` object both of which I couldn't iterate through.

The `test1` that I put in the template is not printing in the page. The `{{form.formname}}` property however is available and is printed in the page.

I've checked many questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29213984/relation-is-ds-promisemany-instead-model-and-data), and the general suggestion is to add the id list but I've added them in the JSON but I don't see the difference

screenshot of ember-inspector data tab:
[image]

What am I doing wrong here? Any ideas?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, is there any other way without using jsonapi... currently using ember and data 2.0.0, and active model adapter...

Comment: I thought it was some crazy environmental issue, but if it is getting reproduced you could post in ember-data issues about this. https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the RESTAdapter was not working for this particular data set or environment, so I decided to scrap it and embrace the new JSONAPI 1.0 specs and use the JSONAPIAdapter.

Models:

create-field.js:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    field: DS.attr(),
    label: DS.attr(),
    tooltip: DS.attr(),
    category: DS.attr(),
    url: DS.attr('string', { defaultValue: ""}),
    required: DS.attr('boolean')
});
```

enable-field.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    field: DS.attr(),
    required: DS.attr('boolean')
});
```

widgetform.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    formname: DS.attr(),
    createFields: DS.hasMany('create-field'),
    enableFields: DS.hasMany('enable-field')
});
```

The JSON for the above model is formatted as per the JSONAPI 1.0 spec: http://jsonapi.org/format/

```
{
  "data": [{
    "type": "widgetform",
    "id": 1,
    "attributes": {
      "formname": "Edit Widget"
    },
    "relationships": {
      "create-fields": {
        "data": [{
          "type": "create-fields",
          "id": "1"
        }, {
          "type": "create-fields",
          "id": "2"
        }]
      },
      "enable-fields": {
        "data": [{
          "type": "enable-fields",
          "id": "1"
        }, {
          "type": "enable-fields",
          "id": "2"
        }]
      }
    }
  }],
  "included": [{
    "type": "create-fields",
    "id": "1",
    "attributes": {
      "field": "widgetName",
      "label": "Widget Name",
      "tooltip": "Widget Name",
      "category": "textfield",
      "required": true
    }
  }, {
    "type": "create-fields",
    "id": "2",
    "attributes": {
      "field": "APIKey",
      "label": "API Key",
      "tooltip": "API Key",
      "category": "textfield",
      "required": true
    }
  }, {
    "type": "enable-fields",
    "id": "1",
    "attributes": {
      "field": "showAdvanced",
      "required": false
    }
  }, {
    "type": "enable-fields",
    "id": "2",
    "attributes": {
      "field": "notification",
      "required": false
    }
  }]
}
```

adapter:
application.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
    namespace: 'api'
});
```

And I was able to access it from the template using the each block as usual

widgetform.hbs

```
<div class="container-fluid">
{{#each model as |form|}}
<form class="form-horizontal">
<fieldset>
<header id="header">
  <h1>{{form.formname}}</h1>
</header>
<section id="main">
    <ul id="field-list">
        {{#each form.createFields as |element|}}
            <li>
                <input name="{{element.field}}" type="text">
            </li>
        {{/each}}
      </ul>
</section>
</fieldset>
</form>
{{/each}}
</div>
```

I hope it helps someone...

Comment: I have the same issue, is there any other way without migrating to json api?

Answer (score 0):

Try `createFields: DS.hasMany('createField')` (singular)

Comment: I tried, but I am getting the same result. Is the JSON incorrect or the models themselves or am i accessing them in an incorrect way? confused:(

Comment: Besides the relationship, everything else is displaying fine? Which adapter are you using?  Are you familiar with [Ember Inspector](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/ember-inspector/installation/)? Any anomalies with models in the Data tab there?

Comment: Everything else is displaying fine. Even the formname attribute is displayed from the same model. I can see the data for all three models in ember inspector. The parent model says that the related models are computed properties.

Answer (score 0):

You're not specifying the relation data that Ember Data needs to make the connection between your models.

In `create-field.js` and `enable-field.js`, you have `widgetform: DS.belongsTo('widgetform')`, but you're not specifying `widgetform_id: 1` on the record payloads.  You might be able to solve this by explicitly setting the `inverse` option in the `belongsTo` and `hasMany` definitions, but I would recommend just adding the relation IDs to your payload.

Comment: you say to add this the `"widgetform_id": 1` in all of my fields like this:        `"create-fields": [{
                "id": 1,
                "field": "widgetName",
                "label": "Widget Name",
                "tooltip": "Widget Name",
                "category": "textfield",
                "required": true,
                "widgetform_id": 1
            }`

Comment: @AlanFrancis correct, ember-data sees the belongsTo and expects to find a `<related model>_id` property on the record.  And of course, make sure the correct IDs show instead of hardcoding "1" ;-)

Comment: Im just starting out to try and do a proof of concept, So the json is a mock served from the ember-cli http-mock, so hardcoding is the way to go here ;) I've made changes to the JSON format, but the behaviour hasn't changed. Updated the OP with the suggested format. Any ideas?

Comment: Try using underscored names instead of dasherized names in the payload, and also try using `DS.ActiveModelAdapter` as your application adapter.

Comment: ActiveModelAdapter is not available in 2.0, it was deprecated and removed :(  https://github.com/emberjs/data/commit/1991ba5f70a64abeec40b48544159405be144bb3

Comment: tried using the underscored names that doesn't work either. it doesn't change the behaviour.

Comment: It wouldn't work without the ActiveModelAdapter.  JSONAPIAdapter is probably the right choice anyway, glad you got it working.